# Using Tor Hidden Services With Python

Tags: python

As you already know in order to use Tor without the Tor Browser you need to have Tor installed on the command line and running afterwards you can configure programs like Curl to use the Tor SOCKS5 proxy on port 9050 I am working on implementing this in Python I have already finished this using subprocess combined with Curl and so far i am using requests combined with a proxy list the only proxy in the list is socks5://127.0.0.1:9050 and this works for clearnet websites i have checked by running the request without the proxy and with the proxy using HTTPBin and they are different IP addresses but i have tried to resolve a .onion domain with this same code but it doesn't resolve with the error Name or service not known. What do I do in order to fix this? And what's the cause

Edit: I read in a previous question that maybe Tor was not running or listening for connections the proxy takes connections  for clearnet websites from the same script and redirects to the Tor network but does not resolve .onion websites and i checked to make sure and Tor is indeed running and listening for connections on port 9050 and i have checked the network connection it is indeed active and can ping clearnet websites but the script won't resolve .onion domains

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
Proxy = {'http' : 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050',
         'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'}
Request_Server = requests.get('https://www.facebookcorewwwi.onion/')
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show your code. We can only guess right now.

Comment: Just added it to the post